# Call endpoint from Google Cloud alias IP range by default

Tags: linux, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a subnetwork on Google Cloud 10.10.0.0/24. There's on VM with the 10.10.0.2 IP. It has an alias IP too: 10.10.9.100.
I'd like to call an endpoint on an other VM, but it doesn't respond as only 10.10.9.100 is whitelisted in the other VM's firewall. How can I change my source address from 10.10.0.2 to 10.10.9.100 in my webservice calls?

I can achieve this with ping with the -I option, so:

ping -I 10.10.9.100 ip_of_other_VM.

But I'm looking for a more general solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the VM recognizes the IP alias ranges as being **local**. 
Connect to VM and try the following:

```
ip route show table local
```

Result would be : `local ALIAS_IP_RANGE dev eth0  proto 66  scope host`
If you do not see alias IP range, please add it using:

```
ip route add to local ALIAS_IP_RANGE dev eth0 proto 66
```

[Configuring alias IP ranges](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-alias-ip-ranges#cannot_connect_to_alias_ip)